# Relative path for JetBrains Projector, or list of all available features for projector-images project?

Tags: jetbrains-ide

I'm trying to run a Projector image (IDEA Community and DataGrip) behind the nginx proxy with relative path, something like:

```
https://myserver.com/projector/aosidjfa-se3f-489r-3849wef
```

But on that URL I can see projector UI which refer to the root of webserver, so all queries going to `https://myserver.com` instead of `https://myserver.com/projector/aosidjfa-se3f-489r-3849wef`.

Is it possible to configure Projector image somehow? I can't find any good documentation about that project.

Comment: **I think** they may have gave up on [Projector project](https://github.com/JetBrains/projector-server) (no much activity in the repo). Have you tried [JetBrains Gateway](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jetbrains-gateway/info) --> https://www.jetbrains.com/remote-development/gateway/ (the GUI will be local but the rest is remote)

Comment: Idea is making technical interview in browser. I don't want force candidates to install something.

Comment: I see. Cannot really help here... but will leave these if they can help in any way: **1)** https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/16015-projector (a plugin to the IDE -- so your IDE can be used as a server) -- maybe it can work this way. **2)** Two introduction articles (in Russian though -- use Google Translate, will be enough to get the overall info) -- No much tech details on your case but it may give you some ideas:  https://habr.com/ru/post/510210/ and https://habr.com/ru/company/JetBrains/blog/548770/